# How to set orientation to Landscape in iText 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am converting html to pdf using iText7 with method convertToPdf(). PDF is getting generated properly but Landscape mode is not working.

Can some one tell how to get Landscape mode?

```
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.css.media.MediaDeviceDescription;
import com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.css.media.MediaType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.CssConstants.LANDSCAPE;

public class htmlToPDF {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();

        MediaDeviceDescription med = new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.ALL);
        med.setOrientation(LANDSCAPE);
        properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(med);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File("D:\\test.html"), new File("D:\\test.pdf"),properties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Please just use a converter method that takes `PdfDocument` as a parameter. For example, the next one : `convertToPdf(InputStream htmlStream, PdfDocument pdfDocument, ConverterProperties converterProperties)`

Now the only thing you need is to set the page size to the document before converting the html file.

```
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new File(sourcePath)));
    pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(destPath), pdfDocument, new ConverterProperties());
```

Comment: Thank you, pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate()) was exactly what I was looking for because I want to rotate only some pages of my document

Comment: Please add below line of code which is missing and creates confusion.
`var props = new ConverterProperties ();`

Comment: @Rapwnezel: and how do you rotate only some pages ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PageOrientationsEventHandler` to handle orientation in your document like -

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PageOrientationsEventHandler eventHandler = new PageOrientationsEventHandler();
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.add(new Paragraph("A simple page in portrait orientation"));
eventHandler.setOrientation(LANDSCAPE);
```

check it in more detail [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/page-orientation-and-rotation).

Comment: But how can I pass html file as input? I am converting a html file to pdf.

Comment: that's a good suggestion if someone wants his document to have pages of different orientation. However if one just want to have some certain orientation set on the whole document, there is no need in handling START_PAGE event